# When opening a file, a warning 'insecure or coming from untrusted source' appears

Tags: security, https

I inherited SharePoint without knowing anything about it and it crashed hard a few weeks ago but we were able to restore most functionality and this is the only thing that is left.  When I open any documents with WopiFrame I get the warnings that the stuff is insecure or coming from an untrusted source.  The SSL cert is valid is installed.  I applied it in bindings.  I also added it to trust relationship in Central Administration.  I also changed it in OfficeWebAppsFarm using PowerShell to point to correct one and rebooted all the servers as suggested and nothing works.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I am sure I am missing just one minor thing that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to say what is wrong from your description you are not specifying what ssl error you are having.

Below you have option how to get to the detail of the error, but what I would suggest is to rebuild the OWA server.As you mentioned you inherited the farm and you are not familiar with the standard operations, this way you will be sure that it is set up as MS describes and familiarize yourself with the process. This is very quick installation, following MS guidelines on installation should set you right.

If you prefer to dig into details of the issue you need to enable CAPI2 logs in windows server (the issue most probably occurs in the OWA server). When you hit the error review the CAPI2 logs and see what is the detail of the issue (most probably part of the chain of the cert is not trusted, if that is the case you may need to export cert and import it to root trust on the OWA server)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  I will try rebuilding the OWA server if I can't resolve the issue any other way.  It is all learning experience.  The error that I am getting when I hit f12 on browser and look at the Console is the following:

Answer (score 0):

You hit all the big stuff, maybe try to reconnect SharePoint and OWA with the New-SPWOPIBinding command.

Comment: First of all thank you for your quick reply. On what server the binding needs to be set.  How do I check the existing settings?  Get-SPWOPIBinging?

Comment: That is correct, you can run the New-SPWOPIBinding command on any SP server, I typically use an application server not a web server.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spwopibinding?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Would the fact that we are trying to use wildcard cert be a possibility as a cause for this issue?  I've read somewhere that it should be a fully qualified certificate. I did not try going that route yet.